# В чём разница между устройством и инструментом?

Tags: значение-слов, семантика

Смотрите, дрель - это инструмент, а домкрат - устройство. Хотя внутреннее устройство электрической дрели, как мне кажется, сложнее устройства домкрата.

Так что же мы называем *инструментом*, а что - *устройством*? И какое соотношение между этими двумя понятиями?

Ещё интересно, как соотносятся с вышеупомянутыми слова *прибор*, *механизм*, *приспособление*?

Comment: Один из тех вопросов, с которыми лучше всего обращаться к толковому словарю, лучше даже не к одному. Все равно ведь тот, кто будет отвечать, без копипасты не обойдется.

Comment: @Niemand Интересны рассуждения людей поверх цитирования, а не только сами отсылки к словарям.

Comment: Вам интересны такие рассуждения? Телега и топор – устройства; новое качество и новое состояние; грабли – устройство или инструмент в зависимости от того, где находятся и т.п. Наслаждайтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(в рамках предложенного контекста)

**Устройство** - искусственно созданный материальный объект для выполнения полезной функции и для этого приводимый в действие (телега, топор, телевизор, водопровод, часы, рогатка, измерительный прибор, летательный аппарат...).

**Инструмент** - материальный объект, используемый в качестве средства выполнения технологической задачи (измерения, обработки материала, проходки тоннеля, воздействия на ткани биологического объекта, шинковки, вычисления...).

Инструмент может быть частным случаем устройства - если он создан искусственно, но может оказаться природным предметом (камень может служить инструментом для колки орехов или заточки ножей). В узком смысле это наименование закрепилось за *ручным* инструментом, и этим словом сравнительно редко называют станки, компьютеры, измерительные и медицинские приборы, сложные технологические установки - отчасти потому, что классификация и специализированные наименования дают начальное представление о размерах, внешнем виде и степени сложности "инструмента", понимаемого в более широком (но прямом, не переносном) смысле как средство выполнения технологической задачи.

Comment: Alex_ander, ну вы хоть сравните то, что написали. У Вас разница сводится к тому, что одним выполняют задачи, а другим - функции. Вы можете внятно объяснить разницу? Дальше не читал, этот шедевр вогнал меня в ступор.

Comment: Александр, вы "топор" относите к устройству?

Comment: @ behemothus Я разделил полезные функции воообще и технологические как частный случай. Чтобы к устройствам не относились дома и прочие полезности, ограничил "приведением в действие" (живой силой или иным источником энергии).  @Серж Топор - и устройство, и инструмент. Устройство - в более широком понимании, например, таком, как в патентной литературе.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вы слишком уж много в одном вопросе спрашиваете. )))
Все зависит от производимого действия, его содержания.
Вообще-то говоря, всякий инструмент можно считать устройством, обратное - неверно.

Если не вдаваться в терминологические дебри, инструмент это то, чем ***производят,*** что-то создают или переводят нечто в новое качество. Дрель производит дырки, точнее из стены без дырки делает стену с дыркой. Это новое качество стены. Т. е. дрель - инструмент.

Домкрат ничего принципиально нового с машиной или грузом не делает - только перемещает. Поднятие не переводит в новое качество, максимум - в новое состояние. Поэтому, домкрат = устройство.

Все, разумеется, до определенных пределов условно. Если микроскопом (прибором, т. е. устройством) начать колоть орехи, то он становится инструментом. А если граблями дверь в сарай подпереть, то грабли останутся устройством но уже не будут инструментом.

С остальными вопросами, думаю, сами разберетесь.

Comment: >> *А если граблями дверь в сарай подпереть, то грабли останутся устройством но уже не будут инструментом.* Это тянет минимум на филологическую кандидатскую. Но один аспект все-таки не освещен: а если на грабли наступить, то они будут инструментом или устройством? А может, прибором и механизмом?!

Comment: Для "инструмента" совершенно необязательно преобразование действительности с образованием нового качества (напр. этого не делают штангенциркулем).

Comment: Это тянет минимум на филологическую кандидатскую - если и на кандидатскую, то никак не на филологическую. С филологией тут все понятно. Грабли подпирающие дверь не производят нового качества двери, но вот неким устройством или частью являются, поскольку имеют полезное воздействие на дверь. А вот грабли, на которые наступили - это, исходя из текущего их действия, не устройство даже, а антропогенное загрязнение окружающей среды. )))

Comment: *напр. этого не делают штангенциркулем* - А я и не ставил так вопрос. Во-первых, печь шла об инструментах механического воздействия, во-вторых, измерительные инструменты, это, строго говоря, - приборы. Ну и некое изменение измеряемого объекта как раз имеет место. Он становится более понятным.